# How to insert a bulk data seperatly into mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, database, nosql

I have a json file that contains three datas together. I want to insert all three datas seperatly into the mongodB. Is that possible? if yes then how?

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "First",           
            "count": 4,
            "name": "Fish",
        },
        {
            "_id": "Second",           
            "count": 6,
            "name": "Meat"
        },
        {
            "_id": "Third",            
            "count": 8,
            "name": "Vegetables"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to insert it through a java based application or via the shell?

Comment: through java..or is there any predefined format of json for mongoDB?

Comment: Documents are stored as JSON, when you ask *if there is a predefied format*, the defined format is JSON. The JSON can be of any structure. When you want to insert multiple documents, you could insert them as an array of documents, your input structure fits perfectly. You need to insert it as `db.collection.insert(input["docs"]);`. Via Java, first you need to load the JSON file, parse it and then insert using the MongoDB java driver.

Comment: mongoDB considering it as a single file . Actually i need all three files i included should insert seperate. Am totally new to this database.

Comment: No way mongodb can consider an array of documents as a single document. Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("docs");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                bson=(DBObject)JSON.parse(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                collection.insert(bson);
            }

Comment: You can compose a `x = ArrayList<DBObject>()` from the `docs` array and, do `collection.insert(x)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a group of documents from the `mongo` client shell:

let,

```
var input = {
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "First",           
            "count": 4,
            "name": "Fish",
        },
        {
            "_id": "Second",           
            "count": 6,
            "name": "Meat"
        },
        {
            "_id": "Third",            
            "count": 8,
            "name": "Vegetables"
        }
    ]
}
```

Inserting the `docs` array:

```
db.collection.insert(input["docs"]);
```

This would insert each item in the `docs` array as separate documents in the collection.

```
db.collection.find();
```

would give us, three different documents that were inserted.

```
{ "_id" : "First", "count" : 4, "name" : "Fish" }
{ "_id" : "Second", "count" : 6, "name" : "Meat" }
{ "_id" : "Third", "count" : 8, "name" : "Vegetables" }
```

To do it in Java, you need to load and parse the `JSON` file using `JSON` parsing libraries such as Jackson parser, get the `docs` array and persist it.